# Ruby script shebang with rbenv and uninstalled project-required version

Tags: ruby, rbenv, env

I have a script in a Ruby application at `bin/setup` that begins with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

`env` tells what executables are accessible, and if there is a Ruby version available on `$PATH`, the script should use it to execute.

Suppose I am using `rbenv` and I have a global Ruby version set (either `system` which falls back to `/usr/bin/ruby` on OS X) or something else. `system` or my global Ruby version is different from the `.ruby-version` declared in the direction within which this `bin/setup` script is being executed. The `.ruby-version` file contains `2.1.6`. This causes the script to instantly abort with:

```
rbenv: version `2.1.6' is not installed (set by /Users/olivierlacan/project/.ruby-version)
```

This means there is no way to rely on `env` to dynamically fetch the appropriate version of Ruby this `bin/setup` script should be executed with.

The only alternative I found is:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
```

But this is not portable to any Linux or Windows OS that doesn't have Ruby installed in `/usr/bin/` like OS X. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem here. It seems that everything is working as designed. Your project is configured to use Ruby 2.1.6 which isn't installed. Thus, any attempt to run Ruby scripts from that project will fail. If rbenv allowed a different Ruby version to be used here other than the one specified in `.ruby-version` file, then rbenv would be broken and not doing its job.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [there's a similar issue](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/187#issuecomment-18202711) in `rbenv` when installing a gem in a specific Ruby version and also globally, due to the way that `rbenv-which` resolves commands.

[The `rbenv-which-ext` extension](https://github.com/yyuu/rbenv-which-ext) by [GitHub user @yyuu](https://github.com/yyuu), the maintainer of [the Python fork `pyenv`](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv), solves at least that problem. An additional patch might be necessary to treat `ruby` as a command in the same way, but it's worth a try. I'll attempt to recreate your problem locally and do the same to verify.